# How to request json from a server and work with the data?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I am trying (in a userscript, using the browser console for tests) to request data in the MIME type application/json.  If I view the source URL in my browser (over the network) I get back a block with a long HTML code with a lot of divs and class elements, which is not really smooth (because that would mean I have to parse it to get the needed data).

Is there a way to receive the JSONs directly in my userscript and work with the data on the fly. So far I’ve got the following code with which I (hopefully) request the information and get it in form of an JSONP to work directly without to parse it.

```
function getJSONP(url, success) {

var ud = '_' + +new Date,
    script = document.createElement('script'),
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] 
           || document.documentElement;

window[ud] = function(data) {
    head.removeChild(script);
    success && success(data);
};

script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
head.appendChild(script);

  }

getJSONP('the_url', function(data){
console.log(data);
});
```

The question is is it correct and also how do I work with it? For example if the jsonp object got the properties lastName, firstName and age how do I get the value of name (data.firstName doesn’t works) or how can I preview the object?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to get JSON from a server then you have to make a request to which the server will response with JSON. How you do that depends on how the server is configured (and in most cases,  you can't). JSONP is not JSON.

Comment: As Quentin says, JSONP, despite its similarity in name, is not JSON. Indeed, it does not necessarily have to involve JSON at all - it's just a name for a means of exposing remote server responses to your environment, (normally) by wrapping them in JavaScript function invocations. If the server is responding with HTML, that's your first problem, and you need to ask whoever runs the server why that is. For an overview of JSONP, I wrote an article some time ago covering what it is, what it isn't, and how it works: http://tinyurl.com/qe5u9hl